# Extend a Styled Component from a different file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, css-in-js

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to add extra styling to my Button.tsx(essentially extending the styles) when using this component in different files. As you can see in my `Button.tsx` I have defined some default styles I would like the button to have, but as I use more buttons across my app, I might want to change the `background` or `color`, etc.

One thing I could do is this:

**Example of not what I want to do:**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

interface IButton = {
  children: string
}

export default function Button({ children }: IButton) {
  const Button = styled.button`
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  `
  const RedButton = styled(Button)`
    // Inherits all of the styles from Button.
    background: red;
  `

  return (
    <Button>{children}</Button
  )
}
```

This example will inherit my `Button` styles and then allows me to extend. The problem with this solution is, if I decide to add more buttons, I will always have to come back to this file and then add the different variants, which could start to make this file get pretty chunky and messy.

Ideally I would like to extend my `<Button>` from the App.tsx file, or which ever file I'm using my `<Button>` in.

---

How could I adjust the code below to achieve this?

**Button.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

interface IButton = {
  children: string
}

export default function Button({ children }: IButton) {
  const Button = styled.button`
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  `

  return (
    <Button>{children}</Button
  )
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default function App() {
  return (
    {/* This button would render with the default styles from Button.tsx */}
    <Button>Button One</Button>
    {/* This button would render with extended styles, a blue background for example */}
    <Button>Button Two</Button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your App.tsx you can do the same:

```
  const BlueButton = styled(Button)`
    background: blue;
  `
```

what styled-components does is it creates a class with background blue and pass it to your Button. so in your Button.tsx you need to accept the css class

```
export default function Button({ className, children }: IButton) {
  const Button = styled.button`
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  `

  return (
    <Button className={className}>{children}</Button
  )
}
```

**Edit**
another way to do is to export the style like this

```
const BaseStyles = css`
    padding: 1em;
    background: #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
`

const BaseButton = styled.button`
    ${BaseStyles}
`
```

Then later override the styles

```
 const BlueButton = styled.button`
    ${BaseStyles}
    background: blue;
  `
```

Comment: Also, it seems that the specificity isn't prioritising the `<BlueButton>` styles, it will only work if I add important: `background: blue !important;`.

Comment: You can add the style like this: && { background: blue; }. This will give higher priority to the overidden styles

Comment: I actually just found this method, is this the only way? Seems like a bit of a hack

Comment: Im afraid so, this is just how css class works now, nothing to do with styled component at this point.

Comment: `&&` is just duplicating the class name to give it higher specificity, if the `<BlueButton>` came after the `<Button>` when compiled, wouldn't it have higher specificity?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, nothing to do with order of compilation here. there is another way to do it. let me update the answer

Comment: What exactly are you `exporting` on the other way of doing it, I don't see an `export`?

Comment: the BaseStyles, you use the BaseStyles to create BlueButton on different files. that way it will just create new css class with blue color without worry about priority

Comment: So I would need to do `export const BaseStyles = css`` ` in Button.tsx, then `import Button, { BaseStyles } from '../components/Button'` in App.tsx?

Comment: yes, then define the BlueButton using that styles + additional styles.

Comment: How do I use it though, if I'm using `const BlueButton = styled.button` ` how does it get passed the props from the `Button` component? Or did you make a mistake and it should be `const BlueButton = styled(Button)` ?

Comment: BlueButton now is just a separate button, just the styles is reuse. if you have any logic in your Button you can't use this way though

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your help! It's certainly appreciated. :)